# How would a write a LINQ query to compare with a list of values?

Tags: .net, linq, list, compare

I have basically to select all employee from companies which are being passed so a variable -

`CompanyListIds` - Contains list of all company ids..

```
var result=DataContext.Employee(e=>e.CompanyId==companyId).ToList();
```

The above is  a query I have for selecting from one company, now how would I modify it to compare with all the companyids that would be passed..how would I use `contains` maybe here..Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result=(from e in DataContext.Employee
           where CompanyListIds.Contains(e.CompanyId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have proper keys set up in the database and the navigation properties configured in your Entity Diagram, you should be able to do:

```
var result = DataContext.Companies.SelectMany(c => c.Employees);
```

But if not, you can simply use Contains:

```
var result = DataContext.Employee
                        .Where(e => CompanyListIds.Contains(e.CompanyId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result= DataContext.Employee.Where(e=> CompanyListIds.Contains(e.CompanyId)).ToList();
```